# Telling VSCode to ignore possibly uninitialized Typescript class property values

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have some code like this:

```
  const vc: ValidationContext = validators[0];
  vc.target = instance.constructor;

  /* tslint:disable */
  expect(vc.target.name).to.equal(instance.constructor.name);
```

Even though I have initialied `vc.target` and added a `/* tslint:disable */` comment VSCode still draws a red squiggly under `vc.target` in the `expect` test.

The warning says:

> Object is possibly undefined

Any ideas on how to disable the warning.  I came up with the `/* tslint:disable */` after reading through a Typescript github issue, but it's not having any effect ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've initialized `vc.target`. But `vc.target.name` might still be null. Hence the error. Also you disabled tslint not typescript

## Fix

Use `//@ts-ignore`

```
//@ts-ignore
expect(vc.target.name).to.equal(instance.constructor.name);
```